# Reimport document into Sharepoint to preserve previous versions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, versioning, word

I have Word document that went through multiple version (in Sharepoint). One of the authors downloaded a copy and make changes and sent me the document via email. Is it possible to add that new document as a new version in Sharepoint. I can copy and paste the document but some of the elements do not paste correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the library has versioning enabled, you can simply upload the document with the same file name as the existing document in the library. The upload dialog will present you with a tick box to add as a new version to existing files. Make sure this box is ticked, then you should be fine.